# Image uploaded is 0 bytes

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

I am using the following task to upload multiple images from android device to server using php.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String url = "http://aerialssnip.com/multipleupload.php/";
            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return sResponse;
    }
```

The images upload without any error both on the android side and the server side. However, the images uploaded are 0 bytes, they do not have any data and i am unable to view them. 
php script

```
      <?php




      $name = $_POST["name"];
     $image = $_POST["IMAGE"];
     $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");


       file_put_contents($path,$decodeImage);



     ?>
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be in my code? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it may just be a typo

Instead of

```
file_put_contents($path,$decodeImage);
```

you probably meant

```
file_put_contents($path,$decodedImage);
```

Comment: In the php error log I am still gettiing one more error. Undefined index: image in /home/melobookco/public_html/multipleupload.php on line 7
[12-Jun-2016 04:54:32...Would you know how I can define that Index?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code - or if it's the above code point out the relevant line?

Comment: Don't see anything that would generate that message in the above code. If $_POST["IMAGE"] was not defined it would produce the message  Undefined index: IMAGE